# Jquery dynamic drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu that is dynamically populated with string text options.  Elsewhere on my page, when a user inputs text into a text box, I need to see if the text entered into the text box matches one of the options in the drop down menu.  If the the text does NOT match I need to check a check box.  How can I achieve this using jquery? I am running into some difficulty because the drop down menu options are dynamic and not static.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this assuming that your dropdown is made up of a list inside a list item:

```
$(textelement).on('change', function() {
     var elements = $(dropdownList).children();
     for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
          if ($(this).value() == elements.html()) {
               $(checkbox).prop('checked', false);
          } else {
               $(checkbox).prop('checked', true);
          }
     }
});
```

I didn't check if this works, but you should get the concept.

Comment: Thanks for your reply muuk. I see where you're going with this. I will try it out.